# Tabelas não são mostradas no Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, sqldeveloper

Tenho várias conexões configuradas no `TNSNAMES.ORA`, e para algumas não consigo visualizar nenhuma tabela se expandir a pasta.
O usuário que estou conectando possui acesso, pois faço as consultas e inserções normalmente.

Encontrei na internet uma dica para habilitar a opção de filtro "Incluir sinônimos", mas não funcionou.

Fiz um teste com a ferramenta PL/SQL Developer da [allroundautomations](http://www.allroundautomations.com/) e nela as tabelas aparecem normalmente, mas a ferramenta é trial por 30 dias.

Como nessa segunda ferramenta as tabelas aparecem, acredito que não seja alguma limitação do usuário que utilizo para me conectar, mas percebi a seguinte diferença no `TNSNAMES.ORA`: as minhas strings que mostram a tabela usam `SERVICE_NAME` enquanto as que não mostram as tabelam usam `SID`.

**Exemplo de string que mostra as tabelas:**

```
BDTESTE = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = serv01)(PORT = 12345))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = BDTESTE)
    )
  )
```

**Exemplo de string que não mostra as tabelas:**

```
BDTESTE2 = 
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.200)(PORT = 12346))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVICE_NAME = bdteste2.xyz.com.br)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui uma forma de acessar todas as tabelas e o restante dos objetos que eu não enxergava.
O usuário que estou fazendo login está associado ao esquema 'x' que visualiza poucos objetos do BD, mas tem acesso aos outros objetos que por alguma limitação de acesso está visível apenas no esquema 'y'. Então só precisei localizar o esquema fazendo o seguinte:

1. Clicar com botão direito sobre a conexão;
2. Localizar objeto do BD;
3. Expandir 'Todos os esquemas';
4. Selecionar o esquema com acesso a visualização de todos objetos e clicar em Ir;

Dessa forma posso visualizar e editar todos objetos do BD, mas infelizmente não encontrei uma forma de mostra-los direto no painel de conexões.

Answer (score 0):

Remova todos os filtro que vc conseguirá visualiza todas as tabelas daquele squema.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]